# Is there way to remotely turn on your Android phone?

Tags: remote-control, power-on

I lost my phone and tried to connect it remotely, but the device kept turning off for 2 days. It's kind of strange. So, is there any way to remotely turn on the phone?

I'm not talking about remotely controlling the device. I'm talking about remotely turning on the cell phone.

If relevant, the phone is Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Comment: What is strange? To switch on your phone you have to press the power button. So no, there is no way to turn on your phone remotely unless you are capable of telekinesis.

Comment: A PC can be remotely turned on because it still has an internet connection (BIOS is capable of doing that, and you have a wire attached to it). A phone doesn't have either.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is impossible. To physically supply power to the phone's chip, you would have to press the power button.

The only workaround would be to have an always-on device attached to the phone that could then use a motor to press the power button.

Comment: Or some other electrical trigger like a USB connection.

Comment: @MatthewRead AFAIK, the only devices that turn on when power is supplied are **some** mediatek devices, and IPhones.

Comment: And one of the generation of Moto G, @DanBrown.

Comment: @DanBrown My Find 7 turns on when plugged in, and it has the extremely common Snapdragon 801. I think it's more about the bootloader than anything else.

Comment: @MatthewRead That would make some sense. However, it's still a case that there is no guarantee OP's phone has this trait in their phone

Comment: @DanBrown absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible since newer phones have embedded battery that is not removable. Since the technology is there, the battery could supply low voltage to the hardware that will power via network/data using your sim. There would have the be a application that works with the devices hardware. This would be a similar configuration as "wake on lan".

Comment: While it 'could' if all your 'could' statuses were met, it doesn't answer the question of *can* it.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215736

Answer (score 1):

Older phones could be turned on by calling the number and letting it ring 10X and it would turn on. I don't know why we can't have that feature in the newer phones. BTW I know this is fact, as I did it several times with my phones when they were lost and I had to turn them on remotely to find them.

Comment: Which model phone(s) are we talking about? 
 This sounds implausible.

Comment: baseband is active as soon as sim card and battery is inserted, no matter if phone is on or off (not even sim pin is necessary)

Comment: @alecxs What? If that's the case, does it even need a SIM card to be active?

Comment: @Michael for IMSI the SIM is required, IMEI is available without SIM of course https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband_processor#Security_concerns