# Remotely power on Android for finding the device

Tags: remote-control, lost-phone, power-on

Can an Android be powered on remotely? My intent is to find my phone if it's turned off.

Comment: Related/duplicate from older Q&A: [Is there way to remotely turn on your Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161059/44325)

Answer (score 5):

Android itself does not provide any functionality to automatically boot itself (except from a simple reboot directly after shutdown).

Some manufacturer modify Android to provide scheduled power on, but the scheduled power-on times have to be configured in the device before power down.

But a remotely initiated boot is impossible, because how would you tell Android to boot? Wifi is powered off, Bluetooth is off, only on some phone USB is active even when powered off (e.g. MTK SoC based devices).

Comment: It might be possible in the (near) future, but as you stated it is not possible currently. https://www.androidauthority.com/pixel-find-my-device-powered-off-3365389/

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, that would solve the problem, but not answer the question as the question is about power on the phone remotely.